# How to make Jenkins execute job only for the files that triggered build?

Tags: jenkins, svn

I have an svn repo and a certain Jenkins job for the stuff therein. Using Jenkins svn plugin's "include regions" feature, I can configure Jenkins to poll changes in certain folders or filetypes. But that is for triggering the job. When the actual job starts to execute, how do I know what were the files whose change triggered the build?

I can easily grep the answer out of svn log in a shell script if there is only one commit that triggers the build. But if there is an unknown number of commits  causing my Jenkins job to start, I'm in trouble.

I'm asking this because I want my Jenkins job to run certain analysis ONLY for those files whose change triggered the build.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple commits pushed at once also can execute the script. So I think you are in trouble already. So please maintain a file in job's workspace such that for every build at the end it will save its `commit id`. In your script, now check from that commit to current (`HEAD`) diff and check for changes in your files as per your constraints. And now run your job if all the conditions are met. Hope this helps.

Comment: That should do the job. I'm just wondering if there is any Jenkins plugin to make things easier.

Comment: [https://plugins.jenkins.io/feature-branch-notifier](https://plugins.jenkins.io/feature-branch-notifier) This might be helpful to you. just check once.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this may be fixed, but just in case, there is also the "Last Changes plugin" from Jenkins.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin

That makes a diff between what was in that environment, and what is about to be pushed and gives you the result.